# which template to use in image slider application in xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2

@Hadley

Hii...all

I am new to the iPhone application development. I am trying to develop one image slider type application using xcode 4.2

can anyone let me know which template should I use i.e. single view application,Tabbed application , or page based application or any other ..  ??

n please also let me know how to use a page controller in the application n how to add new view to display an image in the next view of the application using page controller.

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Fist: As you are new to iOS, start with an empty application. You can learn the most by this.

Second: Read some introduction stuff.

Third: I would recommend for your needs to use a scroll view and load the pictures as they are needed. You can find a video showing how to do this in the developer portals in the WWDC videos (payed account needed).